# Electric running under Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) LTS

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

it is possible to run ROS-Electric on a Machine installed with Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS.

Trying to install Electric on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-desktop-full
```

**Update:**

*Electric Emys (Aug 2011):*

```
Ubuntu Lucid
Ubuntu Maverick
Ubuntu Natty
Ubuntu Oneiric
C++03
Boost 1.40
Lisp SBCL 1.0.x
Python 2.6
```

*So I any case, it will not be reliable to run Electric on a Machine wit **Ubuntu Precise** (12.04)**.*

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37981/electric-running-under-ubuntu-12.04-(precise-pangolin)-lts/) by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there

I compiled Electric from source on my laptop which is running 12.04, as my collaborators are using Electric and I have other projects going on the laptop. I took some notes on the way and they may be helpful for anyone trying to do the same. It seems to work for the things that I am working on at present (OpenNI, OpenCV related), but your mileage **will** vary. It should work for you as far as compiling anyway. If it doesn't, let me know the error because I probably just forgot something.

Here is a list of extra things that I did apart from following the  [ubuntu electric install from source guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source)  (note that I did not add electric to my repositories, but rather the Fuerte repository). Mostly what I do differently is arranging the dependencies so that they are fulfilled. Also note that there are steps missing here with respect to installation of some of the packages since I had already installed Fuerte on this machine, which meant some packages that I need were already there.

In ***ros/rosdep.yaml***...

Under "boost: ubuntu:" add

```
   precise:
     apt:
       packages: [libbost-all-dev]
```

In ***common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml***...

Under "assimp:ubunbu:" add

```
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [libassimp-dev]
```

Under "eigen: ubuntu:" add

```
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [libeigen3-dev]
```

Under "yaml-cpp" add

```
  ubuntu:
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [ yaml-cpp ]
```

In ***bullet/rosdep.yaml***...

Under "glut: ubuntu:" add

```
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [ freeglut3-dev ]
```

In ***vision_opencv/rosdep.yaml***...

At the end of the section on "opencv2.3: ubuntu:" add

```
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv-dev]
opencv2:
  ubuntu:
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv-dev]
opencv2.3.1:
  ubuntu:
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [libopencv-dev]
```

In the file ***visualization_common/ogre/ensure-nvidia-cg-toolkit-is-installed.sh***...

before "if [ -x $INSTALLER ]; then" add

```
if [ -e /usr/include/Cg/cg.h -a \
         -e /usr/include/Cg/cgGL.h ]; then
        for lib_path in /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
        do
            if [ -e ${lib_path}/libCg.so -a \
             -e ${lib_path}/libCgGL.so ]; then
                echo "Package nvidia-cg-toolkit seems to be correctly installed."
                exit 0
            fi
        done
fi
```

In the file ***In vision_opencv/opencv2/manifest.xml***...

Change the following line

```
 <cpp cflags="`pkg-config opencv-2.3.1 --cflags`" lflags="`pkg-config opencv-2.3.1 --libs`"/>
```

to

```
 <cpp cflags="`pkg-config opencv --cflags`" lflags="`pkg-config opencv --libs`"/>
```

I also needed to run in a shell

```
sudo apt-get install libcv-dev libhighgui-dev
```

to get the OpenCV C headers on my machine.

In the file ***stage/rosdep.yaml*** add

```
libjpeg:
  ubuntu:
    precise:
      apt:
        packages: [libjpeg8-dev]
```

Build libgtest as per the instructions at http://askubuntu.com/questions/145887/why-no-library-files-installed-for-google-test-on-12-04...

```
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo cmake .
sudo make
sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/
```

(actually, as I understand it, the correct thing to do here would be to have gtest built for each package individually using cmake, but it seems to be okay this way in our case - see the link at the source for why).

Other packages that I have used that may need special treatment that I took some notes for (let me know if you need a push with these): newer versions of *openni_ros* & *image_pipeline*, *perception_blort* and *brics_3d*.

I hope this is helpful for someone. My suggestion would be to attempt a build and, seeing an error, make the appropriate fix from the above list.

Best wishes

Damien

---

Originally posted by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) with karma: 399 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2012-12-19**:
Note that I have also compiled Electric on Ubuntu 12.10 Qantal (with the exception of Gazebo so far). If you want me to provide my experience in a readable format, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no pre-built packages available for ROS Electric for Ubuntu Precise Pangolin. See also [reps/rep-0003](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) and [Ubuntu 12.04 beta install ROS desktop full](http://answers.ros.org/question/30234/ubuntu-1204-beta-install-ros-desktop-full/?answer=30383#post-id-30383).

As mentioned in [Installing electric on 12.04](http://answers.ros.org/question/36980/installing-electric-on-1204/), you could try to build from source, but I'm not sure that would work, as the Electric build config files are probably missing a lot of info for Precise.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) on 2012-07-05**:
Thanks, you are right.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-05**:
It is almost certainly be easier to upgrade to Fuerte than to maintain an Electric/Precise version on your own.